# Flash - ContextMenu events don't work with IE8 and Chrome

Tags: flash, contextmenu

I succeed to display the menu (ContextMenu AS3 class) but associated events (ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT and ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT) don't work with IE >= 8 and Chrome >= 12:

AS file :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class TestContextMenu extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _contextMenu : ContextMenu;

        public function TestContextMenu()
        {
            _contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            _contextMenu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, function (event : ContextMenuEvent) : void {
                trace('Menu displayed');
            });

            var menuItem : ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem('Item 1');

            menuItem.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, function (event: ContextMenuEvent) : void {
                trace('Menu item selected');
            });

            _contextMenu.customItems.push(menuItem);

            contextMenu = _contextMenu;
        }
    }
}
```

Embed code :

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px">
    <param name="movie" value="menu.swf">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <embed src="menu.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390">
</object>
```

Anyone knows why ? And how can I solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: How is you .swf embedded into your html page? Could you maybe show us your code

Comment: I updated description with AS and embed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue :

There was 2 different versions of Flash player embedded with Chrome. I just disabled one of them (chrome://plugins). I kept the '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/' one.

Answer (score 0):

The html tags required to embed an swf file are different for some browsers.

Firefox, Chrome, .. use `<object>` tags while `IE` uses  tags.

Try using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), which will handle cross browser problems for you.
It even comes with a [handy generator](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_generator_1_2_html.zip&can=2&q=) to assist you with embedding.

Cheers